# How to repetitively output and skip certain values from array by loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, hamming-code

I have array[110] filled with integer (row) of bits (only 1 and 0),
I need to divide it to 7 less rows of bits by output and skip repetitively, starting from certain (marked as next power of number 2) index of array[110] to end of this array[110].

Now by 7 different rows (groups,arrays) I mean rows of bits, starting from bits which indexes are next power of number 2, so: 1,2,4,8,16,32... Also in each next row (group), values have to be output and skipped by the number of index, which is next power of number 2 in array. So for example output 4, skip 4... or output 8, skip 8, and so on to last group, where of index in array is next power of 2.
*Additionally, first bit of this smaller rows is always skipped or marked as unknown ("?")*
*I'll treat that indexes in array[110] starts from 1, not 0 like it's natural in arrays - easier description of my problem.*

In example (i marked indexes of array in "()"):
1(1),1(2), 0(3), 0(4), 1(5), 1(6), 1(7), 0(8), 1(9), 1(10), 0(11).

In this example 1st group (output 1, skip 1) will be: 1(1) <-unknown(?),  1(2)<-skip, 0(3)<-output, 0(4)<-skip, 1(5)<-output, 1(6)<-skip, 1(7)<-output, 0(8)<-skip, 1(9)<-output, 1(10)<-skip, 0(11)<-output...until end of array[110]

2nd group will be (starting from index 2; output 2 and skip 2; first value is considered unknown):
1(2)<-unknown(?),  0(3)<-output, 0(4)<-skip, 1(5)<-skip, 1(6)<-output, 1(7)<-output, 0(8)<-skip, 1(9)<-skip, 1(10)<-output, 0(11)<-output...untill end of array[110]

3rd group will be (starting from index 4 as next power of two; output 4 and skip 4; first value is unknown):
0(4)<-unknown(?), 1(5)<-output, 1(6)<-output, 1(7)<-output, 0(8)<-skip, 1(9)<-skip, 1(10)<-skip, 0(11)<-
skip...until end of array[110]

It's part of Hamming Code. For better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAMLuxdHH8o

Now, my method is to create 7 different arrays, like group1[], group2[]... and manually insert there certain indexes which I want to be skipped. Then in for-loops I fill each next group[] arrays only with "output" bits.

But I’d like for-loop to do it for me repetitively. Just code there to skip each 2, 4, 8 (and so on) values and output each 2,4,8 (...) values. Thus 7 group[] arrays with different, but static "distances" of output and skip. How to do it?

My code is:

```
int skip2 []= {3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47, 
                        50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63,66,67,70,71,74,75,78,79,82,83,86,87,90,91,94,95,98,99,102,103,106,107}; 
          for (int j : skip2)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[j] + "("+j+")"+",");
          if (j%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
```

And for bigger values from later groups (this is from 5th group, so starting from 16 index - but skipping it as it's unknown):

```
for (int m=17; m<110; m++)
        {
            if ((m>=32 && m<=47) && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111)) continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
```

Second way is more mathematical, because I must count how many indexes skip. However maybe there is method to write how many output and how many skip?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

```
        int x=0;
        int sum=0;
        boolean w = true;
        System.out.println("Bity potegi CZWARTEJ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 110; i++)
        {
            if (i<=4) continue;

            x++;
            if (x == 4)
            {
                x = 0;
                w = !w;
            }


            if (i%20==0) System.out.println("");
            if (w) System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+",");
            sum++;
            if (i==109) System.out.println("\n"+sum);

        }
```